# A Table of Sums, but faster

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, functional-style, map

I'm trying to calculate the following lists a_j and b_j from some predefined values. (this is not code, it's just supposed to be a mathematical expression)

```
a = Table[Sum[f[k_i, v_i, ma_j],{i,1,j-1}],{j,lvls}]
b = Table[Sum[f[k_i, v_i, mb_j],{i,j,lvls}], {j, lvls}]
```

f is a compiled function, k and v are pairs in an Association, and ma and mb are indices of lists. lvls is the length of ma, mb, k, and v.

I've tried a lot of things, with every permutation I could imagine of KeyValueMaps, Totals, Sums, Tables, Map, MapIndexeds, etc.... and the following code has been the fastest. Unfortunately it still needs to be way quicker. k and v are defined with `Keys` and `Values` earlier on from the AssociationList, and that's fast enough that I can spare doing it.

```
f = (the compiled function, already plenty fast)
varhelper[x_Real,n_Integer,m_Integer]:=
  Total[Map[f[x,#[[1]],#[[2]]]&,Transpose[{k[[n;;m]],v[[n;;m]]}]]]; 
Table[varhelper[means[[i]],1,i-1],{i,lvls}];
```

I feel like there's some way to do this really quickly and nicely with sequencefoldlist, but I am not sure how to implement that. Earlier I ran this code with the profiler, and found that the map in varhelper is the bottleneck. Does anyone have ideas for how to make this run quicker?

Comment: Use `Accumulate` and as to `b` you need also `Reverse`

Comment: Caution: The notation `k_i` does NOT define a variable but rather a pattern (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that wasn't meant to be code as much as show what I'm trying to do :) little bit of latex leaked in

Comment: Also, @Coolwater, I think that doesn't work because the indices of the means are indices in the table, rather than in the sum?